# Online, real-time, shared JavaScript console?

Tags: javascript, collaboration, jsfiddle

I would like to use an online tool to work remotely with people to do Javascript learning and testing exercises.

The solution could be a shared, public Javascript console.

Does such a thing exist? I have seen http://jsfiddle.net. This works ok, but we have to keep updating our URL every time the other person changes code so it is not real-time and requires an update step on both sides.

I think a low-feature real-time shared console would be a pretty trivial solution to build. I'm thinking of building it myself if it doesn't exist, but I wanted to check first and see if anyone has heard of something like this.

Comment: pst, did you ever end up building or finding such a thing?

Comment: nope. sounds like someone should :)

Comment: Someone awesome built http://coderpad.io. It's exactly what this question is looking for.

Comment: As of late September [(based on this tweet)](https://twitter.com/togetherJS/status/381194995257978880), JSFiddle now supports real-time collaboration using TogetherJS. I haven't tried any other code playground in respect to collaboration, so I can't offer a comparison, but for me this worked rather well; it allowed me to do cross-browser testing with ease.

Comment: Did you found out any good solution for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost two years later, a few great alternatives exist. The real-time enhancements to jsfiddle and plunkr are great, but for this use case, I haven't found any easier than [Coderpad](https://coderpad.io/). It's marketed for doing code interviews and saves a history. Has JS/Coffeescript/Ruby/Java and more.

Answer (score 15):

Here are some links for you:

- Collabedit, Online Code Editor http://collabedit.com/
- Stypi, a realtime editor https://www.stypi.com/ (not about coding)
- ShareJS, Live concurrent editing in your app. http://sharejs.org/ (not about coding)
- Tutti, Test Javascript on different browsers simultaneously http://tuttijs.com/ (not collaborative ?)
- Bonus: a JS console for mobile http://jsconsole.com/

Hope you'll find something useful in there :)

Comment: Looks like I should DEFINITELY leverage ShareJS if I end up writing this console thingy myself.

Comment: Tutti is really, REALLY close. It actually will work in some cases, but it is designed for something different so it has one big downside for my use: it only shares executed code, not typed code, so if I want to provide a not-working "fill in the blank" type code problem, it wouldn't work well.

Answer (score 10):

This answer is 3 years late, but should help if you are still checking this post. JSFiddle now has ***collaboration mode*** - it allows you to voice chat and IM, while editing together. Just click the button in the header and set it up!

http://jsfiddle.net#collaborate

Comment: A little more information on this... They are using a Mozilla JS product, TogetherJS, to accomplish this. https://togetherjs.com/

Comment: Collaborative editing works well for code snippets that fit in one page, but not once scrolling is involved.  Development on the underlying TogetherJS seems to have tapered off so this may not be improved further.

Answer (score 9):

http://syncfiddle.net/ is exactly what you're looking for. Simple clean interface that syncs real-time, but also functions as well as any other site out there. But be careful to save your code, it seems to delete your code after enough inactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try

http://jsbin.com/

http://jsconsole.com/

JSBin is very close to what your looking for. provides HTML, CSS, JS and Console code  practices.

JSConsole on the other hand is very simple only used for console coding ofcourse.